# preg_replace in php to remove tags that are multiple time in sting

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem, I need to purge all font tags in variable:

```
$old = '[FONT=arial]Dit is een tekst [FONT=Courier New]nonononon';
$new = preg_replace('/\[FONT=(.*)\](.*)/', "$2", $old);
echo "\nold   = $old\nnew = $new\n";
```

But the result of this is:

```
old = [FONT=arial]Dit is een tekst [FONT=Courier New]nonononon
new = nonononon
```

The result I want is:

```
old = [FONT=arial]Dit is een tekst[FONT=Courier New]nonononon
new = Dit is een tekst nonononon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your regex lazy, use `(.*?)`

***Ref :-*** [`Regex lazy qunatifiers`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution)

```
\[FONT=(.*?)\](.*?)
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/25WJIP/1/)

---

```
$re = '/\[FONT=(.*?)\](.*?)/m';
$str = '[FONT=arial]Dit is een tekst [FONT=Courier New]nonononon';
$subst = '$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Outputs

```
Dit is een tekst nonononon
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any capture group. You may use this regex to match and remove what you don't want:

```
$old = '[FONT=arial]Dit is een tekst [FONT=Courier New]nonononon';
$new = preg_replace('/\[FONT=[^]]*]/', '', $old);
echo "$new\n";
```

```
Dit is een tekst nonononon
```

`[^]]` is a negated character class that will match any character that is not `]`.